# Meaning of Spring @ManagerResource: persistPolicy, persistPeriod, persistLocation and currencyTimeLimit

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-annotations

What does the following fields mean in Spring `@ManagedResource` used for JMX? There is no Javadoc or related description in [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html).

```
 1. String persistPolicy() default "";
 2. int persistPeriod() default -1;
 3. String persistLocation() default "";
 4. int currencyTimeLimit() default -1;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are passed onto the JMX api - you can find more info about it in the [JMX java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/modelmbean/ModelMBeanInfo.html#getMBeanDescriptor%28%29). Copying the relevant section here -

```
 persistPolicy  : OnUpdate|OnTimer|NoMoreOftenThan|OnUnregister|Always|Never  
 persistLocation : The fully qualified directory name where the MBean should be persisted (if appropriate)
 persistFile    : File name into which the MBean should be persisted
 persistPeriod  : seconds - frequency of persist cycle for OnTime and NoMoreOftenThan PersistPolicy 
 currencyTimeLimit : how long value is valid, <0 never, =0 always, >0 seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that these annotation fields will have no effect - see e.g.: [Did Java 5 forget JMX MBean persistence?](http://www.jroller.com/bogie14/entry/did_java_5_forget_jmx)

Comment: The link you have attached seems to be broken

Comment: That link is well and truly gone - not even archive.org has a copy. But it's been a decade - I think by Googling "Spring @ManagedResource" today, you will find much better information.